# React and progress bar. How can I add progress bar that will work with my input and my data

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar

I need to implement a progress bar in my app. I created Pokemon guessing game. I want to add progress bar to it. Now i have x/151 correct answers. How can I add progress bar also?

I found this: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/progress/

But I don't know how to use it, so if anyone can help.

This is my GuessingGame.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';


class GuessingGame extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            id: '',
            sprite: '',
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { url } = this.props
        const id = url.split('/')[6] //get the id from the end of each pokemon url so that we can generate the sprite url
        const sprite = `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${id}.png`;

        this.setState({
            id,
            sprite
        })
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.guessPokemon();
    }

    guessPokemon() {
        if (this.props.name === this.state.value) {
            alert('You guessed right!')
            this.props.fetchData(true); 
        }
        else {
            alert('You guessed wrong!')
            this.props.fetchData(false);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const guessingForm = {
            textAlign: 'center'
        }

        const guessingGame = {
            display: 'block',
            marginLeft: 'auto',
            marginRight: 'auto',
            marginTop: '15%'
        }

        const pokemonImage = {
            borderRadius: '50%',
            backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
            padding: '3%',
            marginLeft: 'auto',
            marginRight: 'auto',
            marginTop: '5%',
            display: 'block'
        }

        return (
            <div style={guessingGame} className='guessingDiv'>
                <img src={this.state.sprite} style={pokemonImage} alt='pokemon' />
                <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Which Pokemon is this?</h2>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} style={guessingForm}>
                    <input style={{ padding: '1%' }} type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input style={{ padding: '1.5%', backgroundColor: '#FF4D4D', border: 'none', color: 'white' }} type="submit" value="GUESS" />
                </form>
                <h4 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{this.props.score}/151 GUESSED</h4>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default GuessingGame
```

And this is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PokemonList from './components/PokemonList.js';
import GuessingGame from './components/GuessingGame.js';
import './App.css';
// import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pokemon: null,
      showPokedex: false,
      score: 0,
      name: '',
      url: '',
      sprite: '',
      proxyurl: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`,
      pokemonUrl: `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151`
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  //fetch the pokemon data from the pokeapi and randomize an id of pokemon the user will have to guess
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData()
  }

  fetchData = (score) => {
    //had to add proxy url because of No Access-Control-Allow-Origin error and call fetch like this: (fetch(proxyurl + pokemonUrl))
    fetch(this.state.proxyurl + this.state.pokemonUrl)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        let randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * data['results'].length)
        this.setState({
          pokemon: data.results,
          name: data.results[randomId - 1].name,
          url: data.results[randomId - 1].url,
          score: score ? this.state.score + 1 : this.state.score,
        });
        console.log(this.state.name)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  //on click show or close pokedex
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ showPokedex: !this.state.showPokedex });
  }

  render() {

    //homepage 
    const Home = () => {
      const header = {
        backgroundColor: '#FF4D4D',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'white',
        borderBottom: '5px solid black',
        padding: '5%',
        margin: '0',
        position: 'fixed',
        width: '100%'
      }

      const pokedexButton = {
        border: '4px solid black',
        backgroundColor: '#FF4D4D',
        width: '85px',
        height: '80px',
        color: 'white',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '20%',
        right: '5%'
      }

      return (
        <>
          <h1 style={header}>Who's That Pokémon?</h1>
          <GuessingGame
            pokemon={this.state.pokemon}
            name={this.state.name}
            url={this.state.url}
            score={this.state.score}
            fetchData={this.fetchData}
            proxyurl={this.state.proxyurl}
            pokemonUrl={this.state.pokemonUrl} />
          {this.state.showPokedex &&
            <PokemonList
              pokemon={this.state.pokemon} />}
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} style={pokedexButton} className='pokedexBtn'>POKEDEX</button>
        </>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="pokedex">
        </div>
        <Home />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

ProgressBar.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const ProgressBar = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="progress-bar">
      {props.percentage}
      <div className="filler" style={{ width: `${props.percentage}%` }} />
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%</div>
  </div>
  )
}

export default ProgressBar;
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Where are you trying to use it and where are you having issues? Please show an attempt.

Comment: I try to create new component for progress bar or add it to GuessingGame.js and I don't know how to use my data to get progression.

Comment: I suppose a good question to find an answer to is what does "progress" mean in your code. Current score of total to win the guessing game? What does your data look like, can you edit your question to include that?

Comment: Progress bar should be number of correct answers from 151 Pokemon. No matter how much wrong answers you have. Bar should show in percentage how much Pokemon did you guess.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `score` is the current correct count of 151 pokemon, the following will get you a percent of that.

```
const percentCorrect = (this.state.score * 100) / 151;
```

This will likely get you a not so nicely formatted number, i.e. `25.3989854839453`, so I prefer to format it when displaying.

```
Number(percentCorrect).toFixed(2); // '25.40' notice it is now a string
```

Now, in order to display a progress bar you need to ensure a couple things:

- `bootstrap` **and** `react-bootstrap` dependencies
- import or add `bootstrap`'s CSS somewhere in your app

Import the progress bar and instantiate:

```
import ProgressBar from "react-bootstrap/ProgressBar";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

...

  <ProgressBar
    now={percentCorrect}
    label={`${Number(percentCorrect).toFixed(2)}%`}
  />
```

[image: Edit ProgressBarDemo]

**EDIT** Factoring/Componentizing a "Percent Bar"

PercentBar.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ProgressBar from "react-bootstrap/ProgressBar";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const propTypes = {
  percent: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

const PercentBar = ({ percent, ...props }) => (
  // spread extra props first to prohibit overriding prop values
  <ProgressBar {...props} now={percent} min={0} max={100} />
);

PercentBar.propTypes = propTypes;

export default PercentBar;
```

Usage

```
<PercentBar label={percentCorrectLabel} percent={percentCorrect} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I created new component ProgressBar.jsx. I edited my original post. Now I want to add this progress bar component in my App.js. But don't know how. I try this from your answer and something like this <ProgressBar percentage={this.state.score / 1.51}

But dosen't work. How should I define my bar in App.js?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @IvanRadunković Apologies but I've no idea how you got to your attempt from my example. I've updated my answer to show how one could factor/create a percent bar, but to be honest, it is really only mapping a `percent` prop to the underlying `now` prop so it isn't a very compelling reason to create a whole new component (unless you want to also configure more of the props and not expose them out to your percent bar component API).

Comment: I was trying to figure out this, so I got something else. Thanks again for your help. I changed my code with your PrecentBar.jsx

But I still don't know how to use this part?

<PercentBar label={percentCorrectLabel} percent={percentCorrect} />

Where in code should i put it so I can see it? I am confused :S

Comment: @IvanRadunković A good candidate for it's location would *be the component* with the state used to derive a percentage, i.e. `App.js`. Either drop it in after the `<Home />`, or tuck it up in within the `Home` component itself.